# Qapass 1602A LCD screen

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm using a Qapass 1602A LCD screen for a arduino project to display something. When wiring up the screen the text in the code won't show and the backlight is the only visible thing showing to know if it's working, thank you!

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

  // initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
  LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

void setup() {
 // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.print("hello, world!");
  }

 void loop() {
   // Turn off the blinking cursor:
   lcd.noBlink();
   delay(3000);
   // Turn on the blinking cursor:
   lcd.blink();
  delay(3000);
 }
```

My wiring:

```
 LCD RS pin to digital pin 12
 LCD Enable pin to digital pin 11
 LCD D4 pin to digital pin 5
 LCD D5 pin to digital pin 4
 LCD D6 pin to digital pin 3
 LCD D7 pin to digital pin 2
 LCD R/W pin to ground
 LCD A pin 15 to Power 3.3V
 LCD K pin 16 to GND
 LCD VSS pin 1 to GND
 LCD VDD pin 2 to Power 5V
```

More Information:

```
  All the Pins on the LCD
    - VSS, VDD, VO, RS, RW, E, DO, D1, D2, D3, D4, D5, D6, D7, A, K

  Arduino:
    - Arduino UNO R3
```